# How to Asterisk dial an extension on the same channel?(without bridging)

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I am using a 8-port Asterisk card. I have a PBX. I want to call extension "222" from 1 channel(DAHDI/1-1)  , i can do it using

```
exten =>s,1,Dial(DAHDI/3-1/222)
```

it use channel 3 as a bridge. However I want to dial "222" directly.

Actually i will use it for this senario:

```
A is customer 
B is call center member
C is asterisk agi which I use credit card payment on phone line.

A calls B
B take infomations of A then
B tranfer A to C (Dial 111 on the phone)
A finish conversation with C (make payment succesfully)
Then I want to reconnect A and B (dialing B's caller ID (112))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?  You need a channel to dial on.

Comment: I pick up a the phone (my caller id : 112) and dial "111" which is the cable connected to asterisk card. So I am connectted to channel one already. And I want to call "222" using Dial() command. By the way i configure extensions as zap channels.

Comment: @zigg I make more explonations on the question and the comment above

Answer (score 0):

You need create dialplan which will record B(extension) and transfer A to C, after that transfer back A to B(recorded in variable).

However all that still will use channels on card. You can't call not using channels.